Override Azure Functions Environment in Azure Kubernetes Service
I want to ask a question. I have an Azure Function code in Net8 (Isolated) then I push to docker image in Azure Container Registry, then I deploy it to Azure Kubernetes Service.
The question is, how can I override the Azure Functions Environment? I have tried put it in Config Maps, Secrets and in Env Property in Deployment Yaml, but it is still read my appsettings.json not my appsettings.Development.json
I want after it is published, the Azure Functions can read the configuration from appsettings.Development.json
For local, I can override it in launch settings.json by adding environmentVariables property, but how can I do it also when published to Azure Kubernetes?
Thank you

I always recommend to follow microsofts guidelines. This should give you a rough idea what to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-kubernetes-service

Thank you for the reply, but I do not understand, I already tried the config maps.
Also I want to add, that I try to deploy it from App Host and also I am still learning docker and kubernetes, so I need a more detail explanation what to do because I do not have many knowledge about this

Can you try to add the AzureFunctionsJobHost__environment environment variable to your deployment YAML file and set its value to Development. This should allow the Azure Functions runtime to use the appsettings.Development.json configuration file instead of appsettings.json. also share your yaml and docker config

I tried AzureFunctionJobHost__environment, but it is still not read from appsettings.Development.json, for docker I publish it to azure container directly from visual studio
this is the deployment yaml:

spec:   replicas: 1     strategy:     type: Recreate   template:     metadata:       labels:         app: testfunc     spec:       containers:       - name: testfunc         image: testfunc.azurecr.io/testfunction:20240613081713         imagePullPolicy: Always         env:         - name: AzureFunctionsJobHost__environment           value: "Development"         envFrom:         - secretRef:             name: testfunc         - configMapRef:             name: testfunc-env

Problem solved, I forgot to remove CopyToPublishDirectory for my appsettings.Development.json that is why it always read the appsettings.json

aah! I see, good to know it is resolved.

@RaymondKenny It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Posting this as answer to help the SO community facing similar issue.  As Raymond  rightly figured out, to ensure that the Azure Functions app in a Docker container reads the correct appsettings.Development.json file when deployed to AKS, one should check the CopyToPublishDirectory settings in the configuration files. appsettings.Development.json file should not be be copied to the publish directory in project file (.csproj). Only the appsettings.json should be copied, and the environment-specific settings should be managed via environment variables.
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

Thanks, Raymond  for your positive input, which was instrumental in resolving this problem. Feel free to edit the answer to add anything I missed here.
